# Where/when should the DAOImplementation instances be located/created?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, dao, java-ee-7

I am working on a JAX-RS project, with a DAO layer. I am not sure about which architecture to follow.

For example, let's say we have a `ProductDAOImpl` class that implements a `ProductDAO` interface, and a `ProductRS` class as the entrypoint for the products REST service.

**Question 1**
Where should the `ProductDAO` (actually `ProductDAOImpl`) instance be created?

*Options:*
A) In each method of the `ProductRS` class that needs access to the product?
B) As a member of the `ProductRS` class?
(Can this option introduce data races? Not sure how the container handles the REST services classes - Possibly related to question 2 below.)

**Question 2**
Should I use annotations for JAX-RS classes, such as `@Stateless`?

**Question 3**
What are the best practices for the architecture and class relationship in a JAX-RS application with a DAO layer and possibly a Service layer?
(Any links to study for this topic are more than welcome.)

**Question 4**
Should the DAO implementation classes provide static methods? (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214112/should-we-always-use-asynchronous-jax-rs-resources-for-mobile-backend))

*Implementation specific details*
Using Jersey implementation of JAX-RS with Glassfish server and a DAO layer with JDBC access to the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

I wouldn't create instances explicitly. Usually dependency injection it is used for this reason - inject ProductDAO interface in your ProductRS class.

**Question 2 - 3**

Some examples related (although not exact) for your technology stack.

Jersey + Spring example:
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Jersey + Guice example:
http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/lean-example-of-tomcat-82

Guice + Hibernate example:
http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/

Jersey + Hibernate + Spring example:
http://www.benchresources.net/jersey-2-x-web-service-integrating-with-spring-and-hibernate-orm-framework-using-annotation/

**Question 4**

There are no static methods in the provided link ([Should we always use Asynchronous JAX-RS resources For mobile backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214112/should-we-always-use-asynchronous-jax-rs-resources-for-mobile-backend))

**UPDATE**

It is recommended to avoid static methods in DAO because of difficult testing. Related discussions:

- [Using Static methods or none static methods in Dao Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523804/using-static-methods-or-none-static-methods-in-dao-class)
- [How to design a DAO class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232080/how-to-design-a-dao-class)
- [DAO pattern - use Static or non Static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995228/dao-pattern-use-static-or-non-static-methods)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Reg. question 4, they're using `UserDAO.findAllUsers()`, and there's not an instance member of `UserDAO`, so the method must be static (but as I've seen using DI along with static methods doesn't bode well).

Comment: Updated, there are related SO discussions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Q1**: Create 'ProductDAO' instance as a member of the 'ProductRS' class and you can use the same instance in all the methods.

**Answer for Q2**: You can use annotations for JAX-RS classes, if you have state less behavior as your functional requirement then you can use '@Stateless'. '@Stateless' is only needed if you need JavaEE Security on your REST service.